# Call drive Rest API: 400 bad request

Tags: java, android, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to use drive Rest API in my app by following [the official quickstart documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android). I generated a SHA1 key, everything works fine but when I call drive API from android phone, I get `400 bad request`.

How is this caused and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 400 means that the server cannot or will not process the request due to an apparent client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).
Could you please take a look at your HTTP request whether it is what you intended it to be?